# Git branch has diverged after rebase, so why rebase?

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, git-rebase

Recently I came across the notification that my branch has diverged. That was when I made a feature branch, pushed it to remote, and did a rebase with master a few days later when I started working on it again.

```
git checkout -b feature-branch
git push origin feature-branch:feature-branch
```

...and when in master...

```
git pull origin master
git checkout feature-branch
git rebase master
```

But when I want to push my branch again, it says:

```
On branch feature-branch
Your branch and 'origin/feature-branch' have diverged,
and have 67 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
```

I found this answer in "[Git branch diverged after rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016698/git-branch-diverged-after-rebase)":

> Since you'd already pushed the branch, you should have merged in the
>   source branch, rather than rebasing against it.

**Question**

After reading [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/conceptual-overview) I still don't fully understand what I should've done differently in my flow, and why I still want to be using git rebase. Hope someone can explain this, thanks!

Comment: What about the push -f? mentioned in your link (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26349885/6309) If you are alone working on this branch, you can no force push.

Comment: I work in a team, so I think overwriting the remote branch isn't a good idea...

Comment: Then no rebase for you. Merge only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So only rebasing when you haven't pushed your branch yet?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The idea is to rebase only if you haven't pushed yet, to replay your *local* commits.

As soon as you have pushed (and are working in a team), you should not rebase the branch on top of `master`, as it rewrites its SHA1, forcing you to force push the new state of the branch.

[image: http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/media/5-1.png]

Making a `git merge master` into your branch is preferable here: you resolve the conflicts locally, then you can more commits, and a regular push.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBMwq.png]

See more at "[What is the difference between merging `master` into branch and merging branch into `master`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26384695/6309)"

Comment: Sub-Question to this old answer.  What about from `feature branch` do `git rebase master` then `git pull`, handle the merge and `git push`?  If the remote branch is in line with the local branch (you pushed the most recent version), what would be the problem?  Perhaps I am misunderstanding how the internals of Git work.

Comment: @Eppilo Sure, it is just that the rebase of feature on top of master will rewrite its history, resulting in a forced push.