# How to rebase effectively without letting commits pile up locally?

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase, feature-branch

I'm trying to implement a workflow whereby I rebase my feature branch off master before merging it in.  I've found that it's not a good idea to push my local commits on the `feature` branch to the remote repo before rebasing, as that essentially duplicates the commits on the feature branch and requires a subsequent force push as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016698/git-branch-diverged-after-rebase).  (Git 101 I know.)  I definitely don't want to get into the habit of `--force` pushing commits, and by letting commits first accumulate locally without pushing, then rebasing, and *then* pushing I avoid this.

However, I'd like to have my commits pushed to the remote server somewhere before rebasing, particularly in cases when the local repo is on a local machine (which could experience HD failure, etc.).  Is there a way to do this, without `--force` pushing?  I've thought of creating some kind of intermediate `my_work` branch but it seems like this would also lead to the 'local/remote diverged' problem.  Maybe there's a clever (or not so clever) way of doing this I just haven't thought of though.

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with force pushing your `feature` branch, assuming you be the only one working on it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If I get into the habit of force pushing `feature` I could very well slip and force-push a public branch at some point.  YMMV but better for me just to not let that habit form in the first place.

Comment: No.  The rebase workflow you are using includes rebasing `feature` on `master` to put the former branch directly ahead of the latter.  The force push of `feature` is not wrong, and there is really no way to avoid it anyway.

Comment: Let's get the topic out there, once and for all: One way to avoid the fact that you could someday force-push a _public_ shared branch is to **not** have one mirror of a shared branch in your local repo in the first place. I mean, it's not like you can't work with local feature branches if you decide to _not_ use a local main/develop/whatever branch locally. There.... I said it. :-D It's not like it makes it impossible to force-push into a shared branch... but it requires more willfulness to do it: `git push -f some-id-or-local-branch:main`. It's _not_ like you can do it just by accident.

Comment: There is also nothing wrong with saving a temp "copy" of a branch. I save WIP (work in progress) branches all the time. No one else knows about them, no one else sees them, they are just backup. This is totally standard procedure; don't worry, be happy.

Comment: @eftshift0 I see what you're getting at, you're saying work from local feature branch but just keep `main` or `develop` or whatever as a remote-tracking branch — just never check it out to local.

Comment: Still another possibility is to back up to a different server. I do that all the time too (i.e. I've got two remotes).

Comment: yes, @matt. And I see posts everywhere where people checkout main/develop/whatever, pull, then go to their branches, pull there... it's so unnecessary, if you ask me: `git checkout my-feature origin/master;` Days later: `git pull`.

Comment: _and_ you can check them out if you need to.... _just_ checkout the remote branch: `git checkout origin/main` so that it's not created locally.

Comment: @eftshift0 oh yeah, I see, you'll be warned you're in detached head mode and you just laugh a wicked laugh and ignore the warning.

Comment: @eftshift0 You can't merge `feature` into `master` without having `master` checked out locally though can you?

Comment: ??? Ah, what? You mean, merging into the remote master forces you to have a local master? Not at all. You can pull it off, in a different fashion. Taking origin is _the_ remote you are playing with: `git fetch origin; git checkout origin/master; git merge feature -m "my feature"; git push origin HEAD:master`

Comment: By the way.... I am not saying this is like the easiest to pick up. I am _just_ saying that it's a **possibility** to work without having the shared branches locally _and_ it would also avoid you from shooting your own foot by pushing into those branches unwillingly/unknowingly.

Comment: ... and, that was the long route. You could pull it off also from your local branch if you created it from the remote branch: `git checkout feature; git pull; git push origin feature:master`

Answer (score 1):

A possible worfflow would be:

- Create and work on your `feature` branch. Regularly commit your changes.
- (optional) Push your `feature` branch to a backup branch or a different remote server for safety.
- Fetch the latest `master` and rebase your `feature` branch onto it.
- After successful rebase, force push to your `feature` branch if necessary.
- If needed, merge your feature branch into `master` remotely without checking out `master` locally.

```bash
# Working on feature branch
git checkout -b feature
git commit -m "Your commit message"

# Optional: Backup
git push origin feature:feature_backup  # or to a different server

# Rebase
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master

# Force push to feature branch
git push origin +feature

# Merging into master remotely
git fetch origin
git push origin feature:master
```